# I configured setting.py file in Django but it displays CORS ERROR

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, postman

My frontend is React and Backend is Django.
In postman, Django has not CORS error and it works well.
But when I send API(post) in React, it displays CORS error.
I configured settings.py file as follow.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:5173'
]
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
] 


VITE_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
    }
});
const register = (data: any) => apiClient.post('/user/register/', data)
```

But it displays CORS error
[You can see the CORS error here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLYNi.jpg)
How can I fix the CORS error?
Above code is Django and Bottom code is React code.

Also, It works well with Postman but does not work with React.
I am new in Django and am going to learn about it.

Comment: I already installed django-cors-headers and added to middleware

Comment: Can you show how the URLs are configured ?

Comment: The error message indicates that you're including a header named `Access-Control-Request-Headers` to your request. Drop that header from your request. Also, add your client code to your question.

Comment: I updated code. Bottom is react code.
I sent post API like that.

Comment: And It works well with POSTMAN but does not work with React

Comment: Expected: neither the SOP nor CORS apply to Postman.

Comment: Drop all those `Access-Control-Allow-...` headers from your requests; they don't belong there. Then try again.

Comment: I removed it and tried again but it does not works still.

Answer (score 0):

Install from `pip`:

```
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your `installed apps`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
"corsheaders",
...,
]
```

You will also need to add a `middleware` class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...,
"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
"django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
...,
]
```

in `settings.py` add:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
"http://localhost:5173",
"http://127.0.0.1:5173",
)
```

documentation:
https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

On the frontend part this works for angular:
`npm install cors`

not sure for react

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I installed the django-cors-header and added it to middleware

Comment: you still miss 2 steps from my answer

Comment: what is that? I followed your answer.

Comment: redo my answer step by step

Comment: I configured and updated your code already. But it does not work. 
Please explain in detail

Comment: try `npm install cors` for your frontend, i forgot it

Comment: I did it but it does not work.
Should I insert something in package.json or other file?